# Custom onepage controller is not overwritting

Tags: php, magento

I'm using magneto 1.6, i am trying to rewrite the core Onepagecontroller with my custom controller in local pool.

Its working so far, but when i am installing other payment module with custom Onepagecontroller too, 'Its not working'.

Magneto isn't read my custom OnepageController, magneto just read custom OnepageController from other module

Here is my file structure and code :

My Custom OnepageController : **\app\code\local\Sprint\Migs\controllers\Checkout\OnepageController.php**

config.xml file:**\app\code\local\Sprint\Migs\etc\config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
      <Sprint_Migs>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
      </Sprint_Migs>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <models>
          <migs>
            <class>Sprint_Migs_Model</class>
          </migs>
      </models>
    <helpers>
      <migs>
        <class>Sprint_Migs_Helper</class>
      </migs>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
          <migs>
            <class>Sprint_Migs_Block</class>
          </migs>
      </blocks>
      <resources>
            <migs_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sprint_Migs</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </migs_setup>
            <migs_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </migs_write>
            <migs_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </migs_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <default>
      <payment>
          <migs>
            <model>migs/migs</model>
            <active>1</active>
            <order_status>pending</order_status>
            <title>VISA / MasterCard</title>
            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
          </migs>
      </payment>
  </default>
    <frontend>
      <layout>
            <updates>
                <migs module="Sprint_Migs">
                    <file>migs.xml</file>
                </migs>
            </updates>
        </layout>
      <routers>
          <migs>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Sprint_Migs</module>
                <frontName>migs</frontName>
            </args>
          </migs>
          <checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Sprint_Migs_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Sprint_Migs_Checkout</Sprint_Migs_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
      </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here is my custom onepage controller

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'OnepageController.php';
class Sprint_Migs_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController {

    public function saveOrderAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }

        $result = array();
        try {
            if ($requiredAgreements = Mage::helper('checkout')->getRequiredAgreementIds()) {
                $postedAgreements = array_keys($this->getRequest()->getPost('agreement', array()));
                if ($diff = array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements)) {
                    $result['success'] = false;
                    $result['error'] = true;
                    $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.');
                    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                    return;
                }
            }
            if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', false)) {
                if ($data['method'] == 'migs'){
                    $fields = array();
                    $fields['quoteID'] = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
                    $fields['siteID'] = $data['site_id'];

                    $write = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getConnection( 'core_write' );
                    $table = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getTableName( 'sprint_migs' );
                    $write->insert($table, $fields);        
                }
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->importData($data);
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();


            $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['error']   = false;
        } catch (Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            if( !empty($message) ) {
                $result['error_messages'] = $message;
            }
            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $e->getMessage();

            if ($gotoSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getGotoSection()) {
                $result['goto_section'] = $gotoSection;
                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection(null);
            }

            if ($updateSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getUpdateSection()) {
                if (isset($this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection])) {
                    $updateSectionFunction = $this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection];
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => $updateSection,
                        'html' => $this->$updateSectionFunction()
                    );
                }
                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setUpdateSection(null);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
            $result['success']  = false;
            $result['error']    = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.');
        }
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();

        if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a good work in the config.xml, but you better remove the `<use>standard</use>` node under checkout.

Also, have you required the original controller before your class? It should look like this:

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'OnepageController.php';

class Sprint_Migs_Checkout_OnepageController 
           extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    /* Your New / Overrided Functions */
}
```

Comment: I have required the original controller before my class, its working for a moment but when i install other module that overrided onepage controller too, my custom onepage is not working

Comment: take a look my custom onepage above

Comment: the point is i want to save quoteID and my custom field form payment method form into my custom table, so i override the onepagecontroller, do you know the other way ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, i use **observer event** too capture custom field and save into custom table

but i just want to know, what is the different between using observer event and overriding onepage controller ?

Comment: The diffference is that when you override a function, you can alter the whole function's functionality the way you want (basic OOP override http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/overloading-and-overriding.html). On the other hand, if you use an observer, you can manipulate the data provided by the observer and add some extra functionality. For more info about Magento's observers you can visit: http://www.techflirt.com/magento-event-observer-hook-in-magento/